# Why won't my container run?

Tags: nginx, docker, lxc

Ubuntu 15.10

Using this run command with the official `nginx` image:

```
sudo docker run -dit --name="myApp" -p 8181:80 -v /home/username/Documents/My\ Folder/Repos/my-app:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v /home/username/Documents/My\ Folder/Repos/my-app/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro nginx
```

It runs fine without the 2nd VOLUME declaration (without the custom `nginx.conf`), but I recently added it because I need to configure some things (AngularJS html5 routing mode).

My **nginx.conf** (All I did was add the `location` settings, everything else was copied over from the original):

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

location / {
    root /home/username/Documents/My Folder/Repos/my-app;
    try_files $uri index.html;
}

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular ... removing tag

Comment: I didn't plan on adding it originally, it recommended it while I was adding the other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `location` block should be within a `server` block:

```
server {
  location / {
    root /home/username/Documents/My Folder/Repos/my-app;
    try_files $uri index.html;
  }
}
```

A tutorial for some more information: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-file-structure-and-configuration-contexts#the-location-context